# how to make a url rewrite rule exception?

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have a bunch of rewrite rules to redirect visits from domainX to domainY, however now I want show an `index.html` page when people visit domainX, but I still want all the other rewrite rules to apply.

I read on stackoverflow that I can just add something like this at the top:

```
RewriteRule  ^index.html  -  [L]
```

However it's not working. I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?

**NOTE:** Current rewrite config file is available [here](http://pastebin.com/mA8qNW8t).

Comment: It would help if you could post your current rewrite rules. Probably this is best solved with a RewriteCond, but it's hard to say what fits your configuration best if we don't know how it currently looks.

Comment: i have a TON of rules. >650 lines (redirecting all kinds of shop products. does it matter what comes after this? if this is at the top shouldn't it work? I'll post a few, but worry moderators will ban me for trying to advertise.

Answer (score 2):

This would be my solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)whiterabbitpress.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^new-arrivals.html$ http://shop.whiterabbitjapan.com/japanese-language/new-arrivals.html [L,R=301]
[...]
```

This means that all the following rules will only be used when the hostname is *.whiterabbitpress.com, and the path is **not** /index.html.

Kudos to you for posting the actual config instead of munging it, it really makes it a great deal easier to help!

Comment: do I need to insert that condition about /index.html before after every RewriteCond in my script? there are many of them further down. see here http://pastebin.com/mA8qNW8t

Comment: You'd only need that where there's a RewriteCond that would otherwise match, so from a quick glance I don't see that it should be necessary, since there's usually no query string used for index.html.

Comment: hum but is it not working nonetheless D:

Comment: I would suggest you enable rewritelog. Your original suggestion should normally work. You need to find out why it isn't applied. Are these rewriterules in a .htaccess file, or in the httpd.conf (or an included file)?

Comment: btw, lookin at your rules they could probably be massively simplyfied by using a rewritemap...

Comment: OK thanks. I"ll see if I can find someone on odesk who can help. I don't know enough about unix to set or inspect the log. Let me know if you happen to be for hire on odesk!

Comment: I see there's still an open bounty here. I do not understand why it doesn't work for you; I tried the exact same rewrites on my test server where it did work - so I really hope that you can get logging turned on, without that it's very hard to give any further help.